# If any li within ul has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to write an if statement that if any li within a ul has a certain class it needs to insert some text in another div, and if the class doesn't exist within the list items of the ul it needs to insert a different text.
Here's what I've tried:

```
<div class="ae-dropdown dropdown">
    <div class="ae-select">
        <span class="ae-select-content"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu ae-hide">
        <li class='selected'><a>Dr</a></li>
        <li><a>Mr</a></li>
        <li><a>Miss</a></li>
        <li><a>Mrs</a></li>
        <li><a>Ms</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ae-dropdown dropdown">
    <div class="ae-select">
        <span class="ae-select-content"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu ae-hide">
        <li><a>Dr</a></li>
        <li><a>Mr</a></li>
        <li><a>Miss</a></li>
        <li><a>Mrs</a></li>
        <li><a>Ms</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var newOptions = $('.dropdown-menu > li');

newOptions.click(function() {

    if ($('.dropdown-menu > li').hasClass('selected')) {

        $('li.selected').closest('.ae-dropdown').find('.ae-select-content').text($('.dropdown-menu > li.selected').text());

    } else {

        $('li').closest('.ae-dropdown').find('.ae-select-content').text('All');

    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd7xgvua/#&togetherjs=NLBAcrKf4t) as well

Answer (score 3):

Combine the [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [> (immediate child)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selectors, like this:

```
$('ul:has( > li.selected)')​
```

You can view a demo here, this matches only if an immediate child

has class="whatever", without the >, it would match if any descendant had that class.

Alternatively, go the other way:

```
$("li.selected").parent("ul");
```

This would find all the immediate .parent() of elements with that class only.

Comment: Hm just tried this (see the updated fiddle) but still can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

What if you compare the length of selecting all dropdown li's with the class against all dropdown li's?

```
$('.dropdown-menu > li.selected').length == $('.dropdown-menu > li).length
```